# Adding rows to a Gridview that is bound to a SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding, sqldatasource

I am trying to add a row to a gridview dynamically, while the gridview has a SqlDataSource bound to it. Is it possible to add a custom row while the data is still binding? I am coding in vb.

Comment: Please give a little more detail and some sample code. Do you want to add during the OnDataBinding event and add a row after a specific row from your datasource, for example? Or do something else?

Comment: Add the data to the DB and call Databind on the sqlDataSource.

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't add the row into the gridview, you would add the new data to it's datasource and then bind the gridview. The data doesn't need to be in your database, you can retrieve the data and then add it to that object.

```
Public Class MyWebForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim myList = generateNewList()

        myList.Add(New FooBar(4, "Four"))


        GridView1.DataSource = myList
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Private Function generateNewList() As List(Of FooBar)

        Dim mylist As New List(Of FooBar)

        mylist.Add(New FooBar(1, "One"))
        mylist.Add(New FooBar(2, "Two"))
        mylist.Add(New FooBar(3, "Three"))

        Return mylist

    End Function

End Class

Public Class FooBar

    Private Property myID As Integer
    Private Property myName As String

    Public Property id As Integer
        Get
            Return myID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property name As String
        Get
            Return myName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            myName = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        myID = id
        myName = name

    End Sub
End Class
```